# Symfony 3.4 host into heroku : The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: symfony, heroku, hosting, symfony-3.4

I'm working with Symfony 3.4, Well tested on localhost, When I push to heroku, the login is OK the home page is OK but I get an issue with some routes as new_client, new_fournisseur saying:

```
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

The problem was resolved When I modify my AppKernal by making the if true everytime like this:

```
if (true || in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
```

I don't understand why it works by enabling this condition and what should I do to resolve this error in a clean way?? Do someone have any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure your Symfony application is running on prod environment? Usually you have to set env variables: `SYMFONY_ENV=prod`

Comment: heroku config:set SYMFONY_ENV=prod
Setting SYMFONY_ENV and restarting ⬢ vast-river-98800... done, v19
SYMFONY_ENV: prod and the error still.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. In this case, run `heroku logs` to see what's happening.